# Issue with build which build by eclipse and ant script

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jboss

I am trying to build my project using ANT script through Eclipse. By Friday it works fine.... but from last two day whichever build I am building from my workspace, Build is done successfully but when I try to deploy that ear It gives me following Error and my ear not getting deploy.

```
[DispatcherPortlet] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'PreReportController' defined in PortletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context/PreReport-portlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.adgo.portlet.PreReportController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
    The import com.adgo.usercommon cannot be resolved
    The import app cannot be resolved
    The import app cannot be resolved
    The import app cannot be resolved
    The import app cannot be resolved
    The import app cannot be resolved
    The import app cannot be resolved
    The import app cannot be resolved
    The import com.k2.event cannot be resolved
    The import com.k2.util cannot be resolved
    The import com.k2.util cannot be resolved
    CustomeLogger cannot be resolved
```

I Don't know what went wrong. I have 5 workspace with me with all in running state. But now all builds which from all these work space giving me same error. I didn't change my java for Eclipse and JBoss. Please suggest me. I don't know is this problem with my Java/Eclipse/System/Jboss.......

Comment: try to refresh, clean and build projects again in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

There seeme to be some kind of compilation issues with the `com.adgo.portlet.PreReportController` class.

Try to resolve them. Make sure you have all the needed libraries. You might have to put some of the libraries at server side folder too.

If the above two are checked, you shouldn't be facing this error.

Comment: Everything is there at server side. Actually This problem I got for one work space, And then as I told my all workspace throwing same error while deploying build which build by them.

Comment: Have you in recent times, deleted any of the lib folders which might have been referenced to by your project, by mistake? Try to check once. In that case, no matter which workspace you use, the same problem will be thrown @ each place.